pkcon update sub-process error
I'm on KDE Neon and running sudo pkcon update, which is giving the following error:
Fatal error: Error while running the transaction: 
E: Sub-process /usr/share/dpkg/scripts/steam-launcher.sh pre returned an error code (127)
E: Failure running script /usr/share/dpkg/scripts/steam-launcher.sh pre

I don't have steam installed, and that script does not appear to exist. I've tried:

sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt dist-upgrade

but they did not help.

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a KDE/Neon forum.    FYI:   KDE Neon does share a number of support options common with Kubuntu, alas this is not one of them with Neon off-topic here
